# emacs/doom how can I debug hanging TRAMP

Tags: debugging, emacs, tramp

I am trying to access a machine on my network I can ssh (with some important setup in ~/.ssh/config) into easily, however I am getting timeouts, when I try it with `SPC-f-f /ssh:my_machine<tab> -> hang!`

After a while and some heavy usage of my CPU it times out and supposedly I am to get some info about what went wrong in a buffer '*tramp/ssh my_machine*'. However :buffers does not list it and I found no way to access this buffer, everything seems to indicate it isn't actually there.

Any hints?

Is tramp ignoring my .ssh/config?

Comment: Your best bet is to increase `tramp-verbose` to 6 (or to 10, if the former isn't sufficient). Rerun the test, and consult the tramp trace buffer afterwards. if you need help in analysis, you might contact the Tramp ML `tramp-devel@gnu.org`.

Comment: There are many reasons which can cause tramp hang, you can check [here](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TrampMode#h5o-4) first.

Comment: @MichaelAlbinus, beginner's question: where would I put that? I tried putting `(setq tramp-verbose 6)` into config.el, but that didn't seem right (not recognized by syntax highlighting ... I am at that level, yeah)

Comment: Start Emacs like `emacs -l tramp --eval "(setq tramp-verbose 6)"`